# When I get a JsonReaderException in JSON.NET, how do I get the original text that caused the parse exception?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I use a third party library (the MS Bot Framework StateClient to be specific) that in turn uses JSON.NET. Something is being returned to the third party library and that is causing a JsonReaderException.

I don't have access to the raw original text that is causing the parse exception, and I can't intercept the communication because I'm running in an Azure App Service.

The only information I have is the following (which could mean anything):

```
Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: T. Path '', line 0, position 0. at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseValue(
```

� **How can I get the original raw text that caused the parse exception from JSON.NET?**

I was hoping it would be on the JsonReaderException object, but it was not. I also tried hooking up an "Error" handler in JsonSerializerSettings, but that does not contain the original text either.